# Always open default store in Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, ce-1.9.0.1

I have two stores 'English' and 'Arabic'. I have set 'Arabic' store as default store and first time when I open browser 'Arabic' store opens automatically but when I change the store from 'Arabic' to 'English' and close the browser and then open the website again it opens 'English' store.

I want that whenever the website is opened after closing browser the default browser should be always 'Arabic'.

Thank you

Comment: This is normal, this info is set in your cookie in "store" key.

Answer (score 2):

In the index.php file there is following code:

```
Mage::run($mageRunCode, $mageRunType);
```

So you can define a runcode (for example a store code) and a runtype (for example store).

```
Mage::run('arabic', 'store');
```

Of course you have to check if the request url is empty so you don't redirect when a user has already chosen a language:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] === '/') {
    Mage::run('arabic', 'store');
}
```

---

*You can do the same in the .htaccess file, if you use Apache (i didn't work it out completely):*

```
SetEnvIf MAGE_RUN_CODE=arabic
SetEnvIf MAGE_RUN_TYPE=store
```

Comment: Editing core files is not a good practice, better use an observer on `controller_action_predispatch ` event and do the logic there.

Comment: Completely true. It would be better to do it in the .htaccess file or like you say with an observer. And observer is better because it doesn't depend on the server technology